# Catching C# unhandled exceptions from other DLLs

Tags: c#, exception

I have to split up parts of my app into dlls.

I have an unhandled exception event in my Application main, and I'm throwing exceptions in my other DLL to test an exception dump process.

Problem is that it can catch custom exceptions ONLY when they are thrown within a constructor.

I'm assuming maybe my custom exception is being wrapped by a system one, but it couldn't catch divide by zero either (again, testing).

What could I have done wrong?

In the code below. NONE of my handlers are actually ever called. The app terminates silently.

MAIN.DLL

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(Application_UnhandledException);
        Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

    public static void Application_UnhandledException(
        object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(e.ExceptionObject.ToString());

    }

    public static void Application_ThreadException(
object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString());

    }

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dcp.Init();
    }

    public static DefaultCommandProcessor.Dcp dcp = new DefaultCommandProcessor.Dcp();
}
```

OTHER DLL

```
    public partial class Dcp : Form
    {
        public Dcp()
        {

            int y = 0;
            int x = 4 / y;  // caught in unhandled exception event in app.
        }
        public Int32 Init()
        {

            int y = 0;
            int x = 4 / y; // not caught
        }
    }
```

Comment: Provide some code on how to reproduce. This is just saying you can't catch exceptions from dlls, which you **can**

Comment: That won't even compile. Plus it does work as intended, you do get the messagebox with the exception. I get a messagebox with `System.DivideByZeroException: Attempted to divide by zero." etc.

Comment: I can't get it to work with DCP in a separate DLL. You have to put DCP in another dll. I can get it to work if everything is in the same dll.

Comment: I made it into it's own class project (dll)